# Python replacement for PHP's HTTP authentication with PHP

Tags: php, python, apache, authentication

The HTTP Authentication hooks in PHP are only available when it is running as an Apache module and is hence not available in the CGI version.

In an Apache module PHP script, it is possible to use the header() function to send an "Authentication Required" message to the client browser causing it to pop up a Username/Password input window.

Once the user has filled in a username and a password, the URL containing the PHP script will be called again with the predefined variables PHP_AUTH_USER, PHP_AUTH_PW, and AUTH_TYPE set to the user name, password and authentication type respectively.

These predefined variables are found in the $_SERVER and $HTTP_SERVER_VARS arrays. Both "Basic" and "Digest" (since PHP 5.1.0) authentication methods are supported.

Has python any like that?

Comment: Are you asking for a specific framework, or just in general writing CGI scripts in Python? Keep in mind that Python is a language (your question is like asking "is there something like this in C?"); and PHP is more of a framwork.

Comment: Are you talking about a Python CGI script?